# How to su to another user in mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, sudo, su

I came from Linux world , and not familiar with OS X admin.
Now I want to su to another user , but it just not working ...
Where goes wrong here ?

```
smallufo@miniserver:~ $ whoami
smallufo
smallufo@miniserver:~ $ su - postgres
Password:
smallufo@miniserver:~ $ whoami
smallufo
smallufo@miniserver:~ $
```

I input correct password , but why I cannot su to postgres ?

Sorry if it is a dumb question , but I've been stuck with it the whole night...

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`su` should work normally in OS X.  @Scott Warren's idea about the postgres user's shell is a possible explanation, but OS X doesn't use /etc/passwd except during bootup.  Normal users (and groups etc) are stored in .plist files under /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/.  The easy way to look at (and modify) them is with the `dscl` command:

```
dscl . -read /Users/postgres  # prints all user attributes
dscl . -read /Users/postgres UserShell # prints just the default shell
```

If necessary, you can set the shell the same way:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres UserShell /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works ! ... though I don't understand the design consideration of Mac OS X ... I'll bookmark this question.

Comment: OS X doesn't use /etc/passwd because its format is too limited -- a fixed number of fields per user, and no ability to have large amounts of data in the fields.  Compare with a user record in OS X, where you'll often (but not always) find a JPEGPhoto attribute (with a hex-encoded image), an MCXSettings attribute (with an often-huge XML description of the user's managed preference/parental controls settings), etc.  You just can't do that in an /etc/passwd entry.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I think Apple should do something about `su` command as the user experience is very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Postgres installed but check your /etc/passwd file.  The last entry for that user account will be the shell that user uses.  In my passwd file the accounts that shouldn't login (_lp,_postfix,etc.) have a shell of /usr/bin/false but accounts that can login are usually /bin/sh.

Comment: Hi , there is no 'postgres' user in /etc/passwd . But the user does exist. for example: I can see owner of  '/usr/local/pgsql/data' is "postgres" . I don't know how Mac OSX (Snow Leopard) manage users.